# iOS: AudioUnit of current AVAudioPlayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer, core-audio

I am working on an app which uses **AVAudioPlayer** to play a audio file.Thats working fine, but now i want to add ***Equalizer presets***.I have got all presets value from this code

```
AudioUnitGetProperty(AudioUnit instance, kAudioUnitProperty_FactoryPresets, kAudioUnitScope_Global, 0, &mEQPresetsArray, &size);
```

I can change Audio unit property with the following line

```
AUPreset *aPreset = (AUPreset*)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(EQPresetsArray, 7);
AudioUnitSetProperty(AudioUnit instance, kAudioUnitProperty_PresentPreset, kAudioUnitScope_Global, 0, aPreset, sizeof(AUPreset));
```

But problem is i am not able to get AudioUnit of current player/AVAudioPlayer instance.

Is there a simple solution for this task?

Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: There are the following method:
extern OSStatus
AUGraphAddNode( AUGraph inGraph,const AudioComponentDescription * inDescription,AUNode * outNode) 

To Add node.
Is there any to get current node?

Comment: The only way to do this is to not use the AVAudioPlayer, but to create your own audio player out of asset or file readers and Audio Units.

Comment: Thanks Nicholson for your response.But actually i have done with all functionality of player with AVAudioPlayer.It would be very helpful or save a lot of time if we got current AUNode or AudioUnit.

Comment: Can we apply setting>music>eq presets values to my app AVPlayer.Is there any setting we have to set in app?

Answer (score 2):

You could take one step back and use AVPlayer, then add a MTAudioProcessingTap.[Example Code Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AudioTapProcessor/Introduction/Intro.html)